# Can't connect to redis which is running in docker

Tags: docker, redis

Docker was updated and asked me about factory reset because some files were corrupted. Ok, I did it. Now I can't connect to redis, but it worked before.

I use `docker run -p 6379:6379 -d redis` for running the latest redis.
I check it `(printf "PING\r\n";) | nc localhost 6379` but nothing happen.

Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88.
MacOS 11.2.3 (20D91)

Looks like a network issue with resolving from localhost to docker.

```
❯ docker inspect 6377a770196e
[
    {
        "Id": "6377a770196edf1a804d482a89deda2e046817ecb827c2a1afa00b7920f9952f",
        "Created": "2021-04-13T11:16:11.029910005Z",
        "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "redis-server"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 3981,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2021-04-13T11:16:12.472660785Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:de974760ddb2f32dbddb74b7bb8cff4c1eee06d43d36d11bbca1dc815173916e",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/6377a770196edf1a804d482a89deda2e046817ecb827c2a1afa00b7920f9952f/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/6377a770196edf1a804d482a89deda2e046817ecb827c2a1afa00b7920f9952f/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/6377a770196edf1a804d482a89deda2e046817ecb827c2a1afa00b7920f9952f/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/6377a770196edf1a804d482a89deda2e046817ecb827c2a1afa00b7920f9952f/6377a770196edf1a804d482a89deda2e046817ecb827c2a1afa00b7920f9952f-json.log",
        "Name": "/blissful_galois",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "6379/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "6379"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "host",
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3ea4acf29016fed55d4a2c29f109de3013e432a9b3f02e4fdc084d92750fa03a-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8ff9465854165041a94e97a4f10f56c96a9589b2bf6181f12c1d3797195e141d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9bf938f8abdddd10c9a45b033e113e9981df4292d0a07f5eb1df56bc93e1a19e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ab76326e67b49b0b5e89ba83f33ae9787aa4b75ec7497f08825d643e1f87dd02/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7baa2201e34a35ab376faa44542ec94b656bede1134c2f9b3761b7aefe4bfdff/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b7379d15235571165f01eae5d5136e04778421703e30e2ee5cdd0fe63c5e9d8d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/244fff080dbb5c84c603ee4a212686ab44b5c528ef117a92e55697c54d9d2edc/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3ea4acf29016fed55d4a2c29f109de3013e432a9b3f02e4fdc084d92750fa03a/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3ea4acf29016fed55d4a2c29f109de3013e432a9b3f02e4fdc084d92750fa03a/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3ea4acf29016fed55d4a2c29f109de3013e432a9b3f02e4fdc084d92750fa03a/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "057a2307c4c2045ac412e59dda40201a9062c08115d4b67102afe3a05a5c1528",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/057a2307c4c2045ac412e59dda40201a9062c08115d4b67102afe3a05a5c1528/_data",
                "Destination": "/data",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "6377a770196e",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "6379/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.12",
                "REDIS_VERSION=6.2.1",
                "REDIS_DOWNLOAD_URL=http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-6.2.1.tar.gz",
                "REDIS_DOWNLOAD_SHA=cd222505012cce20b25682fca931ec93bd21ae92cb4abfe742cf7b76aa907520"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "redis-server"
            ],
            "Image": "redis",
            "Volumes": {
                "/data": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/data",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "23d13da3b9d547635ca0519e5d2a358b46a3dd8234925d07a6dc0725b2a3eb4b",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "6379/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "6379"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/23d13da3b9d5",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "3ce444ad8732cfbdb1cf59e90835a82b4ee2c5d56ec423ff5bdbce9b22836256",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "14088994d7e24bf472756c9b9204611d0698d29f7c9c34a79fa99788eac39b7c",
                    "EndpointID": "3ce444ad8732cfbdb1cf59e90835a82b4ee2c5d56ec423ff5bdbce9b22836256",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Are you trying inside or outside docker?

Comment: I'm trying to connect outside docker, it works inside.

Comment: Perhaps, you need to get the container IP. What happens if you try "172.17.0.2"?

Comment: Nothing. A terminal just freezes waiting for a response.